# partial correlation coefficient in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, statistics, correlation

I have a data in pandas dataframe like:

```
df = 

    X1  X2  X3  Y
0   1   2   10  5.077
1   2   2   9   32.330
2   3   3   5   65.140
3   4   4   4   47.270
4   5   2   9   80.570
```

and I want to do multiple regression analysis. Here Y is dependent variables and x1, x2 and x3 are independent variables.
correlation between each independent variables with dependent variable is:

```
df.corr():

      X1          X2            X3         Y
X1  1.000000    0.353553    -0.409644   0.896626
X2  0.353553    1.000000    -0.951747   0.204882
X3  -0.409644   -0.951747   1.000000    -0.389641
Y   0.896626    0.204882    -0.389641   1.000000
```

​As we can see here y has highest correlation with x1 so i have selected x1 as first independent variable. And following the process I am trying to select second independent variable with highest partial correlation with y. How to find partial correlation in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pairwise ranks between `Y` (last col) and others**

If you are only trying to find the correlation rank between `Y` and others, simply do -

```
corrs = df.corr().values
ranks = (df.columns[:-1][-corrs[:-1,-1].argsort()]).tolist()
```

Sample run -

```
In [145]: df
Out[145]: 
         X1        X2        X3         Y
0  0.576562  0.481220  0.148405  0.929005
1  0.732278  0.934351  0.115578  0.379051
2  0.078430  0.575374  0.945908  0.999495
3  0.391323  0.429919  0.265165  0.837510
4  0.525265  0.331486  0.951865  0.998278

In [146]: df.corr()
Out[146]: 
          X1        X2        X3         Y
X1  1.000000  0.354387 -0.642953 -0.646551
X2  0.354387  1.000000 -0.461510 -0.885174
X3 -0.642953 -0.461510  1.000000  0.649758
Y  -0.646551 -0.885174  0.649758  1.000000

In [147]: corrs = df.corr().values

In [148]: (df.columns[:-1][-corrs[:-1,-1].argsort()]).tolist()
Out[148]: ['X3', 'X1', 'X2']
```

---

**Pairwise ranks between all columns**

If you are trying to find the rank between all columns between each other, we would have one approach like so -

```
def pairwise_corr_rank(df):
    corrs = df.corr().values
    cols = df.columns
    n = corrs.shape[0]
    r,c = np.triu_indices(n,1)
    idx = corrs[r,c].argsort()
    out = np.c_[cols[r[idx]], cols[c[idx]], corrs[r,c][idx]][::-1]
    return pd.DataFrame(out, columns=[['P1','P2','Value']])
```

Sample run -

```
In [109]: df
Out[109]: 
   X1  X2  X3       Y
0   1   2  10   5.077
1   2   2   9  32.330
2   3   3   5  65.140
3   4   4   4  47.270
4   5   2   9  80.570

In [110]: df.corr()
Out[110]: 
          X1        X2        X3         Y
X1  1.000000  0.353553 -0.409644  0.896626
X2  0.353553  1.000000 -0.951747  0.204882
X3 -0.409644 -0.951747  1.000000 -0.389641
Y   0.896626  0.204882 -0.389641  1.000000

In [114]: pairwise_corr_rank(df)
Out[114]: 
   P1  P2     Value
0  X1   Y  0.896626
1  X1  X2  0.353553
2  X2   Y  0.204882
3  X3   Y -0.389641
4  X1  X3 -0.409644
5  X2  X3 -0.951747
```

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, so which one will be the next independent variable x2 or x3?

Comment: @bikuser I solved for a generic case earlier. I think you want the simple case, which I just added at the start of this post.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

Par_corr = -np.linalg.inv(np.corrcoef(df.values.T)) # 4x4 size
```