# Calculating (partial) correlation from a (shrunken) covariance matrix (Help porting R code to Python)

Tags: python, r, statistics, correlation, covariance

There's a paper that I found interesting and would like to use some of the methods in Python. [Erb et al. 2020](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2590197420300082) implements partial correlation on compositional data and [Jin et al. 2022](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.00496.pdf) implements it in an R package called [Propr](https://github.com/tpq/propr).

I found the function [`bShrink`](https://github.com/tpq/propr/blob/12553b3bcd159649f25d9a0e480250c1eee1d965/R/1-propr.R#L326) that I'm simplifying below:

```
library(corpcor)

# Load iris dataset (not compositional but will work for this case)
X = read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/e3BSEZiK", sep = "\t", row.names = 1, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

bShrink <- function(M){

  
  # transform counts to log proportions
  P <- M / rowSums(M)
  B <- log(P)

  # covariance shrinkage
  D  <- ncol(M)
  Cb <- cov.shrink(B,verbose=FALSE)  

  G   <- diag(rep(1,D))-matrix(1/D,D,D)
  Cov <- G%*%Cb%*%G

  # partial correlation
  PC <- cor2pcor(Cov)
    
  return(PC)
}

> bShrink(X)
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  1.0000000  0.96409509  0.6647093 -0.23827651
[2,]  0.9640951  1.00000000 -0.4585507  0.02735205
[3,]  0.6647093 -0.45855072  1.0000000  0.85903005
[4,] -0.2382765  0.02735205  0.8590301  1.00000000
```

Now I'm trying to port this in Python.  Getting some small differences between `Cb` which is expected but major differences in `PC` which is the partial correlation ([cor2pcor function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/corpcor/versions/1.6.10/topics/cor2pcor)).

I tried using the answers from here but couldn't get it to work: [Partial Correlation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229220/partial-correlation-in-python)

Here's my Python code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.covariance import LedoitWolf

def bShrink(M:pd.DataFrame):
    components = M.columns
    M = M.values
    P = M/M.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
    B = np.log(P)
    D = M.shape[1]
    lw_model = LedoitWolf()
    lw_model.fit(B)
    Cb = lw_model.covariance_
    G = np.eye(D) - np.ones((D, D)) / D
    Cov = G @ Cb @ G
    
    
    precision = np.linalg.inv(Cov)
    diag = np.diag(precision)
    Z = np.outer(diag, diag)
    partial = -precision / Z
    
    return pd.DataFrame(partial, index=components, columns=components)

X = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/e3BSEZiK", sep="\t", index_col=0)

bShrink(X)
#   sepal_length    sepal_width petal_length    petal_width
# sepal_length  -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17
# sepal_width   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17
# petal_length  -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17
# petal_width   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17   -5.551115e-17
```

I'm trying to avoid using Pingouin or any other packages than numpy, pandas, and sklearn.

**How can I create a partial correlation matrix from a shrunken covariance matrix?**

Comment: might be a good use case for chatGPT to convert the R code to python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problems

There are two issues here, the estimation of the covariate matrices are different and the translation of the `cor2pcor` step is wrong.

Let's start with `cor2pcor`. I honestly did not understand very well how you are computing it so I decided to check the implementation in R. If we go on the [`corpcor` implementation](https://github.com/cran/corpcor/blob/master/R/partial.R) we get the function:

```
cor2pcor = function(m, tol)
{   
  # invert, then negate off-diagonal entries
  m = -pseudoinverse(m, tol=tol)
  diag(m) = -diag(m)
  # standardize and return  
  return(cov2cor(m))
}
```

We can also check [the implementation of the R stats package](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/cor.R) to see the implementation of `cov2cor`:

```
cov2cor <- function(V)
{
    ## Purpose: Covariance matrix |--> Correlation matrix -- efficiently
    ## ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Arguments: V: a covariance matrix (i.e. symmetric and positive definite)
    ## ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Author: Martin Maechler, Date: 12 Jun 2003, 11L:50
    p <- (d <- dim(V))[1L]
    if(!is.numeric(V) || length(d) != 2L || p != d[2L])
    stop("'V' is not a square numeric matrix")
    Is <- sqrt(1/diag(V)) # diag( 1/sigma_i )
    if(any(!is.finite(Is)))
    warning("diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful")
    r <- V # keep dimnames
    r[] <- Is * V * rep(Is, each = p)
    ##  == D %*% V %*% D  where D = diag(Is)
    r[cbind(1L:p,1L:p)] <- 1 # exact in diagonal
    r
}
```

With those two functions in mind, we can begin to translate them into Python, make sure to use `pinv` instead of `inv` because your matrix can be singular:

```
def cov2cor(V):
    """
    Convert Covariance matrix to Correlation matrix efficiently.
    
    Arguments:
    V: a covariance matrix (i.e. symmetric and positive definite)
    """
    p, d = V.shape
    Is = np.sqrt(1 / np.diag(V))  # diag( 1/sigma_i )

    r = V.copy()  # keep dimnames
    r *= Is.reshape(-1, 1) * Is.reshape(1, -1)
    np.fill_diagonal(r, 1)  # exact in diagonal
    return r


def cor2pcor(m, tol=1e-15):
    """
    Convert a correlation matrix to a partial correlation matrix efficiently.
    
    Arguments:
    m: a correlation matrix
    tol: tolerance for calculating the pseudo-inverse
    """
    # Invert, then negate off-diagonal entries
    m = -np.linalg.pinv(m, rcond=tol)
    np.fill_diagonal(m, -np.diag(m))

    # Standardize and return
    return cov2cor(m)
```

Finally, we can use those to implement `b_shrink`:

```
def b_shrink(M: pd.DataFrame):
    components = M.columns
    M = M.values
    # transform counts to log proportions
    P = M / M.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
    B = np.log(P)

    # Covariance shrinkage
    D = M.shape[1]
    Cb, shrinkage = ledoit_wolf(B)
    
    G = np.eye(D) - np.ones((D, D)) / D
    cov = G @ Cb @ G

    # Partial autocorrelation
    partial = cor2pcor(cov)
    return pd.DataFrame(partial, index=components, columns=components)
```

Doing this I got the following matrix, I replaced `LedoitWolf` with [`ledoit_wolf`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.ledoit_wolf.html#sklearn.covariance.ledoit_wolf) which is pretty much the same thing on this function:

|  | sepal_length | sepal_width | petal_length | petal_width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sepal_length | 1 | 0.951383 | 0.606789 | -0.188676 |
| sepal_width | 0.951383 | 1 | -0.352785 | -0.0561523 |
| petal_length | 0.606789 | -0.352785 | 1 | 0.867358 |
| petal_width | -0.188676 | -0.0561523 | 0.867358 | 1 |

### The covariance matrix

According to the documentation of [`cov.shrink`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/corpcor/html/cov.shrink.html) the implementation in R is based on [(Opgen-Rhein and Strimmer, 2007)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.2202/1544-6115.1252/html?lang=en) and [(Schäfer and Strimmer, 2005)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.2202/1544-6115.1175/html?lang=en) which build on top of Ledoit-Wolf's work, while Sklearn's shrinkage implements only Ledoit-Wolf shrinkage. This gives slightly different matrices `Cb` in both languages:

In R:

```
             sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width
sepal_length   0.01384628  0.03049407  -0.03983544 -0.08249265
sepal_width    0.03049407  0.09092548  -0.10892279 -0.21334250
petal_length  -0.03983544 -0.10892279   0.13876001  0.26559868
petal_width   -0.08249265 -0.21334250   0.26559868  0.58653240
```

In Python:

```
[[ 0.01425639  0.0286866  -0.03757796 -0.07812832]
 [ 0.0286866   0.09108648 -0.10768074 -0.21175137]
 [-0.03757796 -0.10768074  0.13876641  0.26434719]
 [-0.07812832 -0.21175137  0.26434719  0.58509169]]
```

We would get the same results if we replaced the `Cb` matrix from R in Python. As far as I know, there are no implementations of Rhein, Schäfer, and Strimmer's work in Python.

Comment: Thank you for walking me through the entire process!  This is extremely useful and a lot to unpack.  Great to see an actual answer instead of people trying to cheat the system and just copy/pasting ChatGPT code that doesn't work.